# Seeking collection of Universiade "Lomonosov" past problems

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, self-learning, education

I'm looking for an anthology of past years' *qualifying exam* for Moscow State University's *Universiade "Lomonosov" in mathematics and mechanics.*

I only found the 2022 problems and solutions on the official website, https://universiade.msu.ru

It would be great if there is *some* collection (in any language) of universiade-type problems even from other Russian/CIS universities, even going back to USSR era, either online or published in book form. There are collections for the school-level Olympiads that are, in contrast, relatively easy to find.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.